# android application developement

Tags: android

I am doing the notepad example and i have this error in Notepad1 exercise in notes_row.xml
I have this coding still i have this problem. I dont know the solution plz help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`
```

error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: Remove the ` character after the /> (at the end of the layout_height attribute).

Answer (score 0):

```
1) It is better to have component inside some layout.
2) /> after this there is special character, why? remove that.
```

Comment: It is compulsory to have a component inside some layout? Now way, might be he wants to create a row.xml for ListView.

Comment: to get better format, it is good to have inside layout even for row.xml. But I see what you are saying. Let me change wording in my answer.

Comment: @thinksteep: It is a list item layout so it's OK to have the `TextView` on its own. Your second point is correct, however.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trailing ' at the end of the file to the right of the /> - remove that.